# Is it mandatory for a ViewModel class to have explicit constructors?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is it mandatory for a ViewModel class to have explicit constructors?

### EDIT 1:

My ViewModels contains domain data and some lookup data as follows:

```
namespace MvcMultiList.ViewModels
{
    public class PersonVM
    {
        public Person Person { get; set; }
        public MultiSelectList MultiSelectList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Does model binding still work without explicit ctors?

Answer (score 3):

No, default parameterless is fine.

You can use object initializer to populate it:

```
return View(new MyViewModel
{
   Property = 'value'
});
```

EDIT:

Does model binding still work without explicit ctors?

Yes - default model binding uses parameterless constructors anyway.

If you do not declare any constructor for the class ie. `class Foo { }` C# compiler will generate a default one for you `class Foo { public Foo(){} }`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the standard modelbinding functionality you must have a parameterless constructor on your view models, you can have other constructor overloads as well.